# Call subclass's method from superclass

Tags: python

I am a bit new to Python inheritance.

I want a subclass to inherit from a superclass, and I want a method in the superclass to call a method in the subclass.

In Ruby, this works fine:

```rb
class A
  def foo
    self.bar
  end
end

class B < A
  def init
    foo
  end

  def bar
    puts "I, Bar"
  end
end

B.new.bar
```

When I run this, I see "I, Bar", as I expected.

In Python, however, what I thought to be equivalent code behaves strangely:

```py
class A:
    def foo(self):
        self.bar()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo()

    def bar(self):
        print "I, Bar"

B().bar()
```

When I run that I see printed *twice* "I, Bar".

How can I rewrite the Ruby code in Python? Is it possible, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python `__init__` method is normally called whenever an object is created like `initialize` in Ruby. So rename your `__init__` method in an other name.

I think you mistyped `init` instead of `initialize` in your Ruby code.